# How to add xml header to dom object

Tags: python, xml, dom

I'm using Python's xml.dom.minidom but I think the question is valid for any DOM parser.

My original file has a line like this at the beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

This doesn't seem to be part of the dom, so when I do something like dom.toxml() the resulting string have not  line at the beginning.

How can I add it?

**example outpupt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:aid="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<Section>BANDSAW BLADES</Section>
</Root>
```

hope to be clear.

Comment: It would be good to give an example of what the output should be like.

Answer (score 2):

> This doesn't seem to be part of the dom

The XML Declaration doesn't get a node of its own, no, but the properties declared in it are visible on the `Document` object:

```
>>> doc= minidom.parseString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><a/>')
>>> doc.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> doc.standalone
True
```

Serialising the document *should* include the `standalone="yes"` part of the declaration, but `toxml()` doesn't. You could consider this a bug, perhaps, but really the `toxml()` method doesn't make any promises to serialise the XML declaration in an appropriate way. (eg you don't get an `encoding` unless you specifically ask for it either.)

You could take charge of writing the document yourself:

```
xml= []
xml.append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>')
for child in doc.childNodes:
    xml.append(child.toxml())
```

but do you *really* need the XML Declaration here? You are using the default version and encoding, and since you have no DOCTYPE there can be no externally-defined entities, so the document is already standalone by nature. As per the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-SDDecl): “if there are no external markup declarations, the standalone document declaration has no meaning”. It seems to me you could safely omit it completely.

Comment: Thanks, this is a better answer than mine. Good point on being able to omit that header entirely.