# how to add information to xml file python

Tags: python

i'm using minidom to create an xml file
and I would like to add the header to my file , i.e,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "file.dtd">
```

how can I add it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982887/how-to-add-xml-header-to-dom-object.

Comment: thanks for the answer .. what about <!DOCTYPE > do you have an idea?

Comment: Same here, just append it after the xml declaration line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add xml header to dom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982887/how-to-add-xml-header-to-dom-object)